# How to get all locked users

Tags: fusionauth

Is there a way to get all locked users from fusionauth using the javascript client or by direct REST call? As far as I can see one can get that info only for concrete user and not for all available users.

Comment: Are you running the elastic search engine or the database search engine?

Comment: It's configured with the postgres. I also though that it might be possible to query users trhough the elastic too although I'm even not sure if it's possible to get that info this way.

Comment: You can see which database engine you are using by logging into the admin portal, then navigating to 'system' and then 'about'. You can then look at the 'system' panel, which should tell you the search option you are using (either database or elasticsearch). You should be able to get all locked users with elasticsearch but not with the database.